# Facing an issue with listview display

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having five columns displaying data,the issue i am facing is the fifth column data is not visible its getting hidden as well the column heading and the data are not getting properly aligned.Following is my xml for data display
[image]

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="23" />

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="23" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView22"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="23" />
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="455" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView31"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="554" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView32"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="755" />
     </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="6654" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView41"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="7676" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView42"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="7765" />
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="12" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView51"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="45" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView52"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="644" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the listview xml is has below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="12345617890" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Ramakrisha Tripati" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9876543210" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="13/1/2015" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Rohit Sharma" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#F5D8BA">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="item#\nstyle#"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="M Wt\nD Wt\nCS Wt"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Making\nD Rate\nCS Rate"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Margin\nDis %\nDiscount"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GT\nFSP"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
           />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Comment" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Comment goes here"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAcc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Accept" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRej"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="Reject" />


</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
```

because of that

why you not use tablelayout?

Comment: just change the width

Comment: I need to fix the width of each column,so that the data does not moves into other column if the length is more,kind of transparent margin or so.

Comment: thats why you need use tableview or gridview

Comment: Has in image i have multiple data in each row of a column,is it possible using tableview ?

Comment: after i think again its better to change your listview to gridview.
and yes you can.
gridview just like listview but with column

Comment: see Custom Adapter example in 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69721/discussion-between-pihu-and-aiwiguna).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your All Linear Layouts under "xml for data display"

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

With this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

You can see your fifth Layout.